# How to include font when compiling?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a Java project that has a custom font and when compiled on other computers the font is not the same because my font is not compiled with it. How do I compile with it so it works on other PCs?

This code won't work.  Entered it in all my WindowOpened.

```
   try {
        InputStream istream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/cs_regularttf");
        Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, istream);
    } catch (FontFormatException fontFormatException) {
    } catch (IOException iOException) 

    {
    }
```

EDIT: Using the stack trace method, this is what I get for me code.

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1000)
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:877)
at projetfinal.frmMenu.<init>(frmMenu.java:56)
at projetfinal.ProjetFinal.main(ProjetFinal.java:20)
```

Comment: Google "java include font in jar" for a ton of results.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I did like the results told me but still won't work.

        `try {
            InputStream istream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/cs_regularttf");
            Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, istream);
        } catch (FontFormatException fontFormatException) {
        } catch (IOException iOException) 
        
        {
        }`

Comment: What error do you see if you print it out.  In general, don't ignore exceptions unless you are very confident they don't matter esp if code is "not working"

Comment: Should cs_regularttf be cs_regular.ttf?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Nice find, but that was not it, sadly. Maybe it's my path? My font folder is under CurrentProjectFolder\src\fonts

Comment: @Jack Try getting rid of that leading slash. Other than that, you need to print out the stack trace for those Exceptions you're catching.

Comment: @KevinWorkman What do you mean print the stack trace? Removed slash won't work.

Comment: @Jack Empty catch blocks like you have are the enemy of debugging. You want something like this instead: catch (IOException iOException) { iOException.printStackTrace();}

Comment: @KevinWorkman Oh yeah I know what you mean ok. But I honnestly don't think it will cause an error but I usually add some Joption panes to let the user know there is an error. But didn't know about printStackTrace. I guess it prints the info/error if it happens in the console? I will come back when results.

Comment: Ok. These are console results when running the code. 

http://i.imgur.com/naJJptb.png

Comment: @Jack Please copy and paste your stack trace into your question.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Alright did it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` this will interpret the given path *relative to your current package* (and thus you'd have to put your font in `/path/to/your/classes/package/fonts` within a `resources/` directory of your NetBeans project.

Otherwise you may use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` and omit the package part.

Comment: Still won't work. I did this line of code.    


 `try {
            InputStream istream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/cs_regular.ttf");
            Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, istream);
        } catch (FontFormatException fontFormatException) {
        } catch (IOException iOException) 
        
        {
        }`



My acutal path to the font file is as follow. F:\École\Prog\ProjetFinal\src\resources\cs_regular.tff

Now note also I am formatting my text using the Netbeans IDE properties window to, can that change something?